# SCP command to copy more than one file from remote to remote server?

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal

I use this command single line to copy a folder named 'myFolder1' from remote server to remote server. It works fine.

I run this command in the 'terminal' of 'myserver2'. This is the destination server, I mean the server the folder will be copied to.

```
scp -r myserver@190.93.133.6:/home/myserver/www/wp-content/plugins/myFolder1 .
```

If I need to copy two folders (instead of one)I need to run my command two times (one for each folder) like this:

```
scp -r myserver@190.93.133.6:/home/myserver/www/wp-content/plugins/myFolder1 .


scp -r myserver@190.93.133.6:/home/myserver/www/wp-content/plugins/myFolder2 .
```

**My question:** is there a way to join these two commands into a single command line?

Comment: Just wondering about the down-vote. I don't understand why "This question does not appear to be about programming". What is it about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just use the wildcard character `*` and the quotes `"`.

Here an example:

```sh
scp -r "myserver@190.93.133.6:/home/myserver/www/wp-content/plugins/myFolder*" .
```

But you can also be more precise using [other wildcard characters](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm):

```sh
scp -r "myserver@190.93.133.6:/home/myserver/www/wp-content/plugins/myFolder{1,2}" .
```

*Note the quotes used to wrap the path and the wildcard.*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
scp -r myserver@190.93.133.6:/home/myserver/www/wp-content/plugins/myFolder{1,2} .
```

An asterick definitely works here, but it matches more than 1 and 2 thus may cause unwanted result. Note that `{a,b,c,d}` only works on remote path. So if you want to copy from local to remote server, use this instead:

```
scp -r myFolder1 myFolder2 user@host:/path/
```